# Graphs not appearing on Employers Careers Search

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The Top Technology and Demographics graphs are not displaying correctly on the Careers search http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search

Presumably they are meant to show some stacked bar chart or something similar. The hover-overs work to see the actual value for each category but the graphs looks blank.

This issue happens both in Chrome and Safari.

[image: Missing Images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highcharts.js is dependent on jQuery and a recent bump in version broke the old version of highcharts.js we were using.  As a bonus, highcharts.js used to only let you download a minified version which was always troublesome for helping find bugs, but now they distribute the unminified source with the new version!

Comment: That's really more of a bonus for us, not for them...